# Blazor - Multi bootstrap / Multitenant

Tags: css, blazor, multi-tenant, blazor-server-side

Is there more elegant way how to mix 2 bootsraps/css together in one project?

I have an Blazor application (Server prerendered), which has 2 areas:

- End user ( ordering services ) for customer
- Admin ( administration of stock, prices... ) - just for admin user

I have developed Admin part for example using bootstrap 5 (in reality I have used MudBlazor with its own bootstrap).

I needed to have "End user" part of the web site, where will be used totally different bootstrap ( https://themes.getbootstrap.com/product/space-multipurpose-responsive-template/ ).

I can split 2 web sites to 2 different "Net projects", but customer prefers to have single app, I have not found documented sample how to achieve this, so I have changed _Host.cshtml to "catch" admin pages (and point them to page `Admin.cshtml` )

```
@page "/"
@namespace MultiAreaDemo.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}

@if (Request.Query["admin"].FirstOrDefault() == "1")
{
    Html.RenderPartial("Admin.cshtml", null, ViewData);
    return;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>MultiAreaDemo - End user</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/space-enduser/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="MultiAreaDemo.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
.....
```

And created Admin.cshtml page ( pointing to "admin" bootstrap css ):

```
@page "/admin"
@namespace MultiAreaDemo.Pages.Admin
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>MultiAreaDemo - ADMIN </title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admin/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

All "admin" pages need to be prefixed by `admin'. For example:

```
@page "/admin"
<h3>AdminHome</h3>
....
```

As a result the page https://localhost:44398/admin is using `css/admin/bootstrap.min.css` and https://localhost:44398/ is using `css/bootstrap/space-enduser/bootstrap.min.css`

Hope it helps. If anyone knows more elegant way, I would appreciate it.

Comment: This can be done very simply by using different layouts for user and admin pages. You really don't need all the extra complexity of a dynamic css loader, as shown in the selected answer.  For more information, see https://blazor-university.com/layouts/using-layouts/

Comment: @Roberto, do you mean described _Host.cshtml and Admin.cshtml 'customisation' described in the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch CSS - and almost anything else in the header - like this:

Define your Css link as follows giving it an id:

```
   <link id="dynamicCssLink" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
```

Define some JS Code that gets included in your site - I normally use site.js:

```
window.DynamicCss = {
   setCss: function (elementId, url) {
        var link = document.getElementById(elementId);
        if (link === undefined) {
            link = document.createElement(elementId);
            link.id = elementId;
            document.head.insertBefore(link, document.head.firstChild);
            link.type = 'text/css';
            link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        }
        link.href = url;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Define a Class for the JS Interop Code:

```
    public class InteropLibrary
    {
        protected IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; }

        public InteropLibrary(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
            => JSRuntime = jsRuntime;

        public ValueTask<bool> SetDynamicCss(string elementId, string url)
          => JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("DynamicCss.setCss", elementId, url);
    }
```

Register it in services

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<InteropLibrary>();
```

Create an alternative `site.css`.  Mine - site-black.css - looks like this:

```
@import url('open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css');

html, body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color:black !important;
    color: white !important;
}
....
```

My test `Index` page looks like this:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn @this.buttonColour" @onclick="SwitchCSS">@this.buttonLabel</button>
</div>

@code {
    [Inject] private InteropLibrary? interopLibrary { get; set; }


    private bool isDark;
    private string css => isDark ? "/css/site-black.css" : "/css/site.css";
    private string buttonLabel => isDark ? "Switch To Light" : "Switch To Dark" ;
    private string buttonColour => isDark ? "btn-light" : "btn-dark" ;

    private async Task SwitchCSS()
    {
        this.isDark = !this.isDark;
        await interopLibrary!.SetDynamicCss("dynamiccsslink", this.css);
    }
}
```

#### Example Implementation switching stylesheets between the Index and Counter Pages

Layout.razor:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

..... Mark-up

@code {
    [Inject] private InteropLibrary? interopLibrary { get; set; }

    private string _stylesheet = "/css/site.css";

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await interopLibrary!.SetDynamicCss("dynamiccsslink", _stylesheet);
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

DarkLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

..... Mark-up

@code {
    [Inject] private InteropLibrary? interopLibrary { get; set; }

    private string _stylesheet = "/css/dark-site.css";

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await interopLibrary!.SetDynamicCss("dynamiccsslink", _stylesheet);
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Index

```
@page "/"
@layout MainLayout
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
.....
```

Counter

```
@page "/counter"
@layout DarkLayout

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>
....
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint. 

I assume, than for "admin" and "end user" pages you need to have the code in `_Hosts.cshtml` 


```@if (Request.Query["admin"].FirstOrDefault() == "1")
{
    Html.RenderPartial("Admin.cshtml", null, ViewData);
    return;
}```

than I would create new Layout and there I could use your solution with dynamic Js. 
Or do you have some hint, how to „split“ the "admin" and "end user" pages ?

Comment: No, do it with Blazor Layouts.  See my updated answer.